# Como converter varias imagens .jpgs para um único arquivo pdf em c#

Tags: c#, windows, pdf

O que tenho é um diretório com por exemplo, 10 imagens digitalizadas.Gostaria de ler estas imagens neste diretório e converter em um único arquivo .PDF.Eu sei que existem Dlls no mercado que fazem isso mas gostaria de eu mesmo fazer a rotina. Será que seria possível?

Comment: Se você não quer usar uma biblioteca pronta, você pode sempre olhar a [especificação do PDF](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) e criar o PDF baseado nas suas imagens. O formato PDF não é demasiadamente complicado, e a especificação é bem completa.

Answer (score 2):

Por você não ter nada feito, vou te passar o que tenho aqui..talvez não seja 100% o que deseja, mas vai te dar um caminho.
Uma ideia basica, talvez você tenha que reajustar as imagem.

```
//Cria um novo documento
iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 20, 20);
//Salve o documento
string PDFOutput = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(PDFOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));

//Abra o PDf
Doc.Open();

string Folder = "C:\\Images";
foreach (string F in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.jpg")) {
    // Inserir uma pagina
    Doc.NewPage();
    //Adicionar uma Imagem
    Doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Jpeg(new Uri(new FileInfo(F).FullName)));
}

//Fechar pdf
Doc.Close();
```

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme, era isso mesmo que eu queria, ja implementei um teste e deu certíssimo"Muito obrigado!!!